# SoundPool is not loaded?

Tags: java, android

I was creating this code for an android app but it just doesn't play anything when I hit the buttons..
the app used to crash but I fixed it,now it just doesn't play.
I really don't understand what is wrong with this code,everything looks fine to me :O

Thank you for your help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int[] sounds;
    SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(9, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);


public void buttonClicked(View view) {

    sounds = new int[9];

    // fill your sounds
    sounds[1] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.goodmorning, 1);
    sounds[2] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mynameis, 1);
    sounds[3] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.speakenglish, 1);
    sounds[4] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.thankyou, 1);
    sounds[5] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.whattime, 1);
    sounds[6] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.yourname, 1);
    sounds[7] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.yourwelcome, 1);
    sounds[8] = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.closesttoilet, 1);


       if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        soundPool.play(sounds[1], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
    }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[2], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button3) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[3], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button4) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[4], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button5) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[5], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button6) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[6], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button7) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[7], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }

        else if (view.getId() == R.id.button8) {
            soundPool.play(sounds[8], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
        }
}




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Comment: Loading the sounds takes a while and should be done before a button is clicked. I'd move the `load()` calls to `onCreate()`.

Comment: SoundPool also has an [OnLoadCompleteListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener) which could be used to get an `onLoadComplete()` callback when a loading event of a sound resource is completed.

Comment: Thank you too Markus :)